# Both Try Catch gets called every time using Async/Await?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, async-await

Action creators -

```
const startFetching = () => ({
  type: CONSTANTS.START_FETCHING
});

const stopFetching = () => ({
  type: CONSTANTS.STOP_FETCHING
});

const receiveData = (payload, error) => ({
  type: CONSTANTS.RECEIVE_DATA,
  payload,
  error
});

export const fetchData = () => async dispatch => {
  dispatch(startFetching());
  try {
    console.log('TRY BLOCK');
    const data = await getData();
    dispatch(receiveData(data, false));
    dispatch(stopFetching());
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('CATCH BLOCK');
    dispatch(receiveData(error, true));
    dispatch(stopFetching());
  }
}
```

API -

```
export const getData = () => callAPI().then(toJson)
```

Reducer -

```
const data = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CONSTANTS.RECEIVE_DATA:
       return action.payload;
    default:
       return state;
}

const loading = (state = false, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CONSTANTS.START_FETCHING:
      return true;
    case CONSTANTS.STOP_FETCHING:
      return false;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  data,
  loading
});
```

Everytime I call action creator `fetchData`, it dispatches the action `START_FETCHING` then after few milliseconds it calls the API & then it logs `TRY` to the console & returns 200 response & all the data perfectly well but then it logs `CATCH` to the console & then it dispatches the action `RECEIVE_DATA` then it dispatches `STOP_FETCHING`

I have tried using Callbacks & Promises but it results in the same error

The problem is in the try block as it requests the endpoint & receives data as shown in the `NETWORK` tab of chrome developer tools but then it goes into catch block

Comment: Is `dispatch` a function? What is purpose of using `try..catch`? What is `error` at `catch`?

Comment: What `error` do you get?

Comment: Don't you want to `return action.payload` instead of `state.data` when receiving data?

Comment: @Bergi I get this as an error object
{
line:57525
column:75
sourceURL:http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false
}

Comment: @Bergi I've just made up this example for demo purposes..the original code is same as this just a bit complex...edited the question 

Comment: @guest271314 `dispatch` is used in [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) for dispatching an action

Comment: What is `error` within `catch`?

Comment: `error` is `{
line:57525,
column:75,
sourceURL: 'http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false'
}`

Comment: You still have not stated what the error is? What does `console.error(error)` log within `catch` block?

Comment: I did twice checkout the comment above 

Comment: No, you have not stated what `error` is. You have posted an object.

Comment: `error` as in the variable in the `catch` block right?

Comment: Yes. What is `error`? Does `getData()` perform a `fetch()` call?

Comment: Actually its an abstraction provided by an API so I'm just calling a method which calls `fetch` internally

Comment: The issue appears to be related to the `fetch()` call. Not certain why you still have yet to post what `error` is?

Comment: The `error` you are asking its that object only & nothing else is going wrong with my code except TRY & CATCH both get executed

Comment: Is `sourceURL` the URL which is passed to `fetch()`?

Comment: The `fetch` call isn't the issue as it was working when I was pure REACT now that I have added REDUX I guess I've screwed up something

Comment: If you have to guess you cannot possibly be certain what the issue is or is not. Is `sourceURL` the URL passed to `fetch()`?

Comment: I'm using [Unsplash API](https://github.com/unsplash/unsplash-js#photoslistcuratedphotospage-perpage-orderby) so `fetch` isn't the issue

Comment: Checkout the link above that is the method I'm getting the data from

Comment: What is at `line:57525` of your code?

Comment: Its the code in my reducer I think I can figure this out now I'll post the answer as soon as I'm done Thank you so much 

Comment: I got the answer. I was pretty stupid. I was calling a method on an object that didn't exist yet. So it was `getData.user.name` but `getData.user` did not exist. Again Thank You  The error was on the same line but it was pretty big file so I didn't felt the need to open bcz I thought it would be minified & uglified. Sorry my mistake & Thank You